# The value of attribute price_view must be set in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, bundled-product

I am trying to create bundle product from c#.net, but it is throwing error.

> The value of attribute price_view must be set

```
try
            {

            learningProductProductRepositoryV1Service objSrvc = new learningProductProductRepositoryV1Service();
            objSrvc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("democustomer", "kujpuds24jceio16du96a24rj2pilnw5cd3g");//ay9669xbavrxoed2jxpduno858cwrgxs5rej

            LearningProductProductRepositoryV1Product_multiCreateRequest objP = new LearningProductProductRepositoryV1Product_multiCreateRequest();
            objP.product = new CatalogDataProductInterface[1];
            objP.product[0] = new CatalogDataProductInterface();
            objP.product[0].name = "Computer Kit Components";
            objP.product[0].price = 201.00f;
            objP.product[0].priceSpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].sku = "CKC";
            objP.product[0].status = 1;
            objP.product[0].statusSpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].visibility = 4;
            objP.product[0].visibilitySpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].weight = 3.00f;
            objP.product[0].weightSpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].typeId = "bundle";
            objP.product[0].attributeSetId = 4;
            objP.product[0].attributeSetIdSpecified = true;

            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes = new CatalogDataProductExtensionInterface();
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem = new CatalogInventoryDataStockItemInterface();
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.qty = 125;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.isInStock = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.isQtyDecimal = false;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.useConfigMinQty = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.minQty = 1f;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.useConfigMinSaleQty = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.minSaleQty = 1f;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.useConfigMaxSaleQty = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.maxSaleQty = 1000f;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.useConfigBackorders = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.backorders = 0;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.useConfigNotifyStockQty = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.notifyStockQty = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.useConfigEnableQtyInc = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.enableQtyIncrements = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.useConfigManageStock = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.manageStock = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.stockItem.isDecimalDivided = false;

            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions = new BundleDataOptionInterface[1];
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0] = new BundleDataOptionInterface();
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].required = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks = new BundleDataLinkInterface[2];
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0] = new BundleDataLinkInterface();
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].isDefault = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].optionId = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].optionIdSpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].position = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].positionSpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].qty = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].qtySpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].sku = "KB";
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].canChangeQuantity = 0;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].canChangeQuantitySpecified = false;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].price = 3.0f;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[0].priceType = 1;

            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1] = new BundleDataLinkInterface();
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].isDefault = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].optionId = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].optionIdSpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].position = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].positionSpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].qty = 1;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].qtySpecified = true;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].sku = "HD";
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].canChangeQuantity = 0;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].canChangeQuantitySpecified = false;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].price = 2.0f;
            objP.product[0].extensionAttributes.bundleProductOptions[0].productLinks[1].priceType = 1;

            var result = objSrvc.learningProductProductRepositoryV1Product_multiCreate(objP);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to set `price_view` attribute in your code. Please check below image, Price View is required field while creating bundle product.

[image]

As per the Magento

> Price View : Determines if the product price is shown as a range, from
>   the least expensive to the most expensive (Price Range), or with the
>   least expensive shown (As Low As). Options include: Price Range / As
>   Low As.

For more Information please visit this [link](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-bundle.html)  or [this](http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-create-a-bundle-product-in-magento-2-0.html). Please check [this sample CSV](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ac99d4b3a7d86fd1428ed1f5ca215d7f/catalog_product.csv) file for bundle product Import.

Comment: in `customAttributes` I need to pass `bundle_price_view` or `price_view`?

Comment: You can try with the price_view

Comment: yes I have passed `.attributeCode = "price_view"`  and `.value = "0";` but returned **could not save options**  Error.

Comment: then there must be different error. this error has been solved. For that you can ask new question